# nest xml in an xml doctype entity

Tags: xml, entity, cruisecontrol.net, doctype

```
<!DOCTYPE cruisecontrol [
    <!ENTITY triggers "<triggers><intervalTrigger seconds="30" /></triggers>">
    <!ENTITY rootdir "J:\pathyness\" >
]>
```

I'm trying to setup my first cruisecontrol.net server, so since I want to reduce the amount of repeated configuration I am trying to setup this nested XML entity so I can just use `&triggers;` within the body of the xml.

What do I need to do to that XML entity `<triggers><intervalTrigger seconds="30" /></triggers>` to make sure it will work as I've illustrated above? I know that the two gotchas so far are

- quotes
- angle brackets

So I'm not sure if I have to go so far as `&lt;triggers&gt;&lt;intervalTrigger seconds=&quot;30&quot; /&gt;&lt;/triggers&gt;` as that all seems like overkill of the nth degree.

Comment: It may be that section 4.5 is helpful http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#TextEntities

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try going like this:

```
$ cat doctype-markup.xml
<!DOCTYPE cruisecontrol [
<!ENTITY triggers "<triggers><intervalTrigger seconds='30' /></triggers>">
<!ENTITY rootdir "J:\pathyness\" >
]>
<cruisecontrol>
<dir>&rootdir;</dir>
<eins>&triggers;</eins>
<zwei>&triggers;</zwei>
<drei>&triggers;</drei>
</cruisecontrol>

$ xmllint doctype-markup.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cruisecontrol [
<!ENTITY triggers "<triggers><intervalTrigger seconds='30' /></triggers>">
<!ENTITY rootdir "J:\pathyness\">
]>
<cruisecontrol>
<dir>&rootdir;</dir>
<eins>&triggers;</eins>
<zwei>&triggers;</zwei>
<drei>&triggers;</drei>
</cruisecontrol>

$ xmllint --noent doctype-markup.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cruisecontrol [
<!ENTITY triggers "<triggers><intervalTrigger seconds='30' /></triggers>">
<!ENTITY rootdir "J:\pathyness\">
]>
<cruisecontrol>
<dir>J:\pathyness\</dir>
<eins><triggers><intervalTrigger seconds="30"/></triggers></eins>
<zwei><triggers><intervalTrigger seconds="30"/></triggers></zwei>
<drei><triggers><intervalTrigger seconds="30"/></triggers></drei>
</cruisecontrol>
```

Comment: So really what you're saying is that I should just use the single quote ... thanks, that confirms what I suspected was right. Also, doubleupboat for the dump ;) thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to reduce repetition [Configuration Preprocessor](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Configuration+Preprocessor) is vastly superior to working with entity subtitution.

Comment: Yeah, I stumbled on to that as well, but this question was novicely interesting in its own right, so I figured I would ask it. It actually extends to XML preprocessing of it's own accord, so it's just tangentially related to CCNet